Unable to Enable RedisGears on Existing Database in Redis Enterprise Cluster
I’m currently working on my thesis project to implement a write-through or write-behind pattern for my use case where my Redis Enterprise Software server is running on AWS EC2.
However, I’m facing an issue where I cannot find how to add the RedisGears module to an existing database. When I navigate through the Redis Enterprise Admin Console, there is no option to add or enable RedisGears for the database.
I am using Redis Enterprise version 7.8.2, and RedisGears is already installed on the cluster. But, I don’t see the "Modules" section under capabilities or any other place where I can enable or configure RedisGears for a specific database.
And when creating a new database, I can only see 4 modules available under the Capabilities menu: Search and Query, JSON, Time Series, and Probabilistic.
Could anyone guide me on how to enable RedisGears for my database in this setup?
I expected to see RedisGears as an available module under the capabilities, similar to how other modules like Search and JSON are listed. I also tried creating a new database, but the only modules available are Search, JSON, Time Series, and Probabilistic, with no option for RedisGears
Thank you
Installed Redis Modules
Database Configuration Edit
Modules/Capabilities option when creating new database

RedisGears is not part of the 3 feature sets available with Redis Enterprise 7.8.2. You can get in touch with Redis support.

See also https://redis.io/docs/latest/operate/oss_and_stack/stack-with-enterprise/install/add-module-to-cluster/ and https://redis.io/docs/latest/operate/oss_and_stack/stack-with-enterprise/gears-v1/installing-redisgears/

@LiorKogan Thanks for the answer! I have resolved the issue. When creating a database, we need to change the database version to 6.2.13 and disable RESP3. After doing this, the RedisGears option will appear in the Capabilities section, allowing it to be enabled for the new database.
Additionally, Redis support team informed me via email that if we cannot add RedisGears to an existing database, we need to migrate your data from the old database to a new one
